# Vue use computed property in a form

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I have a dynamic form that allows a user to add the item they need, the quantity and the cost per item

```
   <div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in inputs" :key="k">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.item">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.quantity">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.cost">
    <span>
      <i class="fas fa-minus-circle" @click="remove(k)" v-show="k || ( !k && inputs.length > 1)">Remove</i>
      <i class="fas fa-plus-circle" @click="add(k)" v-show="k == inputs.length-1">Add fields</i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>

  </form>
```

I'm then calculating the total cost of all the materials combined using a computed property as follows:

```
  computed: {
      totalCost: function () {
        let total = 0
          for (let i = 0; i < this.inputs.length; i++){

          total += this.inputs[i].cost * this.inputs[i].quantity
          }

          return total

      }
  },
```

What, I the want to do is pass the value of the total cost to a form using the data property as follows. However the `total_cost` field remains undefined.

```
 data () {
        return {
            inputs: [{
            item: '',
            quantity: '',
            cost: '',
            maintenance_id: this.maintenance_id,
            total_cost: this.totalCost,
        }],
```

How do I pass a computed property to a form so that it can be submitted as part of that form?

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the submit by yourself like this

```html
<button @click.prevent="onSubmit">Submit</button>
```

and send all the data from here.
you can acess total as `this.totalCost` inside `onSubmit` function and you do not need that `total_cost` data property